# AWS SCPs and how to block access to certain resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I want to block access to certain resources that I create as a base set up in new AWS account in my Organization. I want to do this for all users except Admins. The access only for admin part is solved with this design:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/myadminrole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/sso-region/AWSReservedSSO_myrolename"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the above role everything is denied for everyone except the admins, this not i want to do I want to block access to certain resources. The simplest way to do so is just to list the resources I want to block access to under "Resource". But this will resolve in manual work to keep this SCP up to date and this is something I try to avoid. So my second idea was to use tags and base the deny of access on them with a condition like this:

```
"Condition": {"ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"aws:TagKeys": ["mytagkey"]}}
```

But when I ran into this issue where some AWS services don't support authorisation based on tags, see link:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#:~:text=Yes-,AWS%20Lambda,Partial%C2%B2,-Amazon%20Lightsail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#:%7E:text=Yes-,AWS%20Lambda,Partial%C2%B2,-Amazon%20Lightsail)

Does anyone know a good way to solve my issue? Or does I just have yo accept that I have to manually update my SCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation both from me and AWS support this is not possible at the moment. So the answer is that you need to manually update your SCPs.